# What was the question asked to Magnus Carlsen which he refused to translate?

Tags: world-championship, carlsen, press-conference

Does any one know what was the question asked to Magnus Carlsen on 7th Nov during inaugural press conference of world championship 2013 which he refused to translate in english? And also, what was the answer he provided?

Answer (score 7):

According to [Tarjei Svensen](https://twitter.com/TarjeiJS), the question was "Kasparov compared you to Harry Potter this week, Stensbøl compared you to Petter Northug, which comparison do you prefer?" to which he replied that he preferred to be compared to real people, therefore Northug. See [this Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/Jonathan_Rowson/status/398582082001059840).

Comment: As a Norwegian I can confirm this is exactly what was said.